# Why does Eclipse Helios show only limited amount of output?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6

Using my Java program and Eclipse Helios , I am trying to print a large output on the console. 
The 'Console Buffer Size' in the Eclipse->Preferences->Console is 1000000 characters, but still console shows only last ~3350 characters (~76 lines). 
Does anyone know why is it so? And how can I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why eclipse behaves that way. I do **always** disable the buffers, this works since version 2.0 or so (Indigo screenshot).

[image]